# Camel set CXF timeouts with Java DSL

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I'm pretty new to camel and stuck with a problem.

I am trying to create a dynamic web service proxy (which is working) using the cxf endpoint. Everything is going well except I have no idea how to set the cxf endpoint timeouts using the Java DSL.

I have found many articles on how to do it using Spring configuration, but I am trying to achieve this by using only Java DSL.

Here is what I currently have , please could someone point me in the right direction on how to manipulate the CXF timeout's (connect/receive) using the Java DSL

```
public void configure() throws Exception
{

    onException(Exception.class).handled(true).transform()
            .method(MyExceptionHandler.class, "handleException");

    CxfEndpoint inboundCxf = new CxfEndpoint();
    inboundCxf.setAddress(soapProxyConfig.getBaseUrl()
            + soapProxyConfig.getAddress());
    inboundCxf.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    inboundCxf.setDataFormat(DataFormat.RAW);
    inboundCxf.setServiceName(new QName(soapProxyConfig
            .getTargetNamespace(), soapProxyConfig.getRemoteServiceName()));
    inboundCxf.setPortName(new QName(soapProxyConfig.getTargetNamespace(),
            soapProxyConfig.getRemotePortName()));
    inboundCxf.setWsdlURL(soapProxyConfig.getRemoteWsdl());

    SedaEndpoint sedaEndpoint = new SedaEndpoint();
    sedaEndpoint.setConcurrentConsumers(100);
    sedaEndpoint.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
    sedaEndpoint.setSize(100);
    sedaEndpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    sedaEndpoint.setEndpointUriIfNotSpecified("seda:" + routeId + "-Queue");

    Endpoint[] remoteEndpoints = new Endpoint[soapProxyConfig
            .getRemoteUrls().size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < soapProxyConfig.getRemoteUrls().size(); i++)
    {
        Endpoint endpoint = camelContext.getEndpoint(soapProxyConfig
                .getRemoteUrls().get(i));

        endpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);
        remoteEndpoints[i] = endpoint;
    }

    from(inboundCxf).routeId(routeId)
            .routePolicy(new WebServiceRoutePolicy()).to(sedaEndpoint);
    from(sedaEndpoint).routeId(routeId + "-Queue").loadBalance()
            .roundRobin().to(remoteEndpoints).id("Out");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some testing and pulling my hair out I found that I was going about it the totally wrong way.

I dont need to set the inbound CXF timeout values, I just need to set the outbound http timeout value which gives me the desired timeout detecetion.

So now I have  a route that looks like this

```
        onException(Exception.class).handled(true).transform(
            method(SoapExceptionHandler.class, "handleException"));

    SedaEndpoint sedaEnpoint = createSedaEnpoint();
    JettyHttpEndpoint jettyEnpoint = createJettyHttpEndpoint();

    CxfEndpoint cxfEnpoint = createCxfEndpoint();

    from(cxfEnpoint).routeId(getRouteName()).to(sedaEnpoint);
    from(sedaEnpoint).to(jettyEnpoint)
            .routeId(getRouteName() + "-endpoint");
```

And for anyone who wants to know how to set the timeout for the JettyProducer here we go

```
private JettyHttpEndpoint createJettyHttpEndpoint() throws Exception
{
    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = new JettyHttpComponent();
    jettyComponent.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    jettyComponent.setHttpClientMinThreads(proxyConfig
            .getMinRemoteClientThreads());
    jettyComponent.setHttpClientMaxThreads(proxyConfig
            .getMaxRemoteClientThreads());

    JettyHttpEndpoint jettyEnpoint = new JettyHttpEndpoint(jettyComponent,
            "jetty:http", new URI(proxyConfig.getTargetEndpointUrl()));
    jettyEnpoint.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    jettyEnpoint.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut);
    jettyEnpoint.setThrowExceptionOnFailure(false);
    jettyEnpoint.getClient().setTimeout(
            proxyConfig.getRemoteEndpointTimeout());

    return jettyEnpoint;
}
```

With that configuration and setting the timeout in the Jetty endpoint I now get my configurable timeout :)